# Update the mysql column with merge of two ROW values

Tags: mysql

I have a table `user_brand` in my database, which stores information about brand which user buy. Assuming that my table has no dependency on another table, table looks like this:

```
User_ID  |   Brand      | meta_key
---------+--------------+-------------
1        |   Killer     |  Name
1        |   Lewis      |  Name
1        |   Pepe       |  Name
1        |   Cloth      |  Product
2        |   Samsung    |  Name
2        |   Motorolla  |  Name
2        |   CellPhone  |  Product
3        |   Acer       |  Name
3        |   Laptop     |  Product
```

Now I want my brand column to update so that the output will be like below, and if `meta_key` is duplicated it will be fine for me, I have not much concern about that.

```
User_ID  |  Brand           
---------+-----------------------
1        |  Killer, Lewis, Pepe
2        |  Samasung, Motorolla
3        |  Nisaan
```

I achieved to get the output in select query and i.e

```
SELECT User_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Brand) 
FROM user_brand 
WHERE meta_key = "Name" 
GROUP BY User_Id
```

But tried so many way to update that particular column but failed.

Some tried query is:

```
UPDATE user_brand  
SET Brand = (SELECT max 
             FROM 
                 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Brand) AS max 
                  FROM user_brand  
                  WHERE meta_key = "Name" 
                  GROUP BY User_id) AS t)

UPDATE user_brand AS t1 
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         GROUP_CONCAT(brand) AS max 
     FROM user_brand 
     WHERE meta_key = "Name" 
     GROUP BY User_id) AS t2 
SET t1.Brand = t2.max
```

Any help, it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below - You've to add `ON Clause`

```
UPDATE user_brand  t1 
JOIN 
(SELECT User_id,GROUP_CONCAT(brand) as max FROM user_brand where meta_key = "Name" 
group by User_id 
) AS t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id 
SET t1.Brand = t2.max
```

Comment: Thanx for the help but it throw an error.  [  #1054 - Unknown column 't2.User_idd' in 'on clause'  ], but after inserting User_id before GROUP_CONCAT(brand), it worked for me. Thanx again for your valuable comment.